# Is there any special meaning when the market price for a stock exactly equals ask or bid?

Tags: stocks, trading

When a stock is ask for 15.2 and bid for 14.5, and the last market price was 14.5, what does it mean? Or what if the last price is 15.2?

Comment: There are many previous posts that explain these terms: [A](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/24085/7926), [B](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/29379/7926), [C](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/22991/7926), [D](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/6809/7926)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a stock is ask for 15.2 and bid for 14.5, and the last market price was 14.5, what does it mean?

It means that the seller wants to sell for a higher price than the last sale while the buyer does not want to buy for more than the last sale price.

> Or what if the last price is 15.2?

The seller is offering to sell for the last sale price, but the buyer wants to
buy for less.

Comment: Thanks, but who decides the market price?

Comment: Market price is more or less the average of all asks and bids quoted by the brokers.

Comment: The market as a whole decides the market price.  See my comment on your question above.

Comment: Actually the market price is simply the last price the instrument was traded at.